# Add ValidationRules into a single xaml line OR shorthand ValidationRules

Tags: wpf, binding, shorthand, validationrules

I'm using a PasswordBox which exposes a dependency property such that I can bind to it. The problem is that by using it like so, I cannot shorthand the Binding.ValidationRules to this syntax:

```xml
<PasswordBox services:RPLPasswordBoxBinder.BindPassword="True" 
             services:RPLPasswordBoxBinder.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=LoginUser.Parola, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> 
</PasswordBox>
```

I set my ValidationRules to a textbox like this:

```xml
<TextBox.Text>
   <Binding Path="LoginUser.Parola" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
       <Binding.ValidationRules>
           <some validation rule/>
        </Binding.ValidationRules>
   </Binding>
</TextBox.Text>
```

Is there any way to specify the ValidationRules collection to my PasswordBox in a single xaml line? Or maybe there's another clever solution for validating user input into my password box?

Some clarifications:

I'm using MVVM and I don't want to use code behind.

I want to add only a single ValidationRule. Maybe the problem with shorthanding Binding.ValidationRules is that this property is a collection. One validationrule would suffice in my situation.

There's a similar question on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3243130/869594). My problem is different as I don't just want to increase readability but actually validate my PasswordBox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you use a Binding ValidationRule within 1 line in xaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44296652/can-you-use-a-binding-validationrule-within-1-line-in-xaml)

Comment: This was originally asked almost a decade ago and Florin hasn't been seen since 2016. Maybe a new answer and explanation of differences between the code then and now in a new answer would be better.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I suggest that you base your data model class on IDataErrorInfo and then validation is performed there and not in the code behind.

There are plenty of examples, but [here's one for starters](http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-idataerrorinfo-for-validation-in-mvvm-with-silverlight-and-wpf/) and another [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/idataerrorinfovalidation.aspx).

Comment: Worked like a charm. For beginners though, I would suggest [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo(v=vs.95).aspx) for an example. I found it easier to read and reproduce.