# Can you use a Binding ValidationRule within 1 line in xaml?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I don't know the correct wording to describe what I'm trying to do here... so I'll just show it.

This xaml I know works:

```
<TextBox>
  <TextBox.Text>
    <Binding Path="Location" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
      <Binding.ValidationRules>
        <domain:NotEmptyValidationRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True"/>
      </Binding.ValidationRules>
    </Binding>
  </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

But this is pretty verbose. I would like to do it in a way similar to this...

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Path=Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                       ValidationRules={domain:NotEmptyValidationRuleMarkup ValidateOnTargetUpdated=True}}"/>
```

I made a class called `NotEmptyValidationRuleMarkup` that returns an instance of `NotEmptyValidationRule`, and it sort-of works. Project builds just fine, it runs just fine, everything works exactly as I expect it to. However, I can no longer view my window in the designer. It gives me an Invalid Markup error because `The property "ValidationRules" does not have an accessible setter.`. And it's true, ValidationRules does not have a setter. If I try to set ValidationRules through code in C# I get a compile error.  But for some reason when I assign it in XAML it actually does build and run just fine. I'm confused. Is there a way I can make this work without jacking up the design view of my window?

Comment: Lets start with *why* it works in XAML... `ValidationRules` is a collection, so instead of calling its setter, it will just `Add` new elements to the collection. I don't know about bringing the collection initialization into a markup extension.

Comment: But according to the designer, it is *not* supposed to work in XAML, even though it is working. I'm trying to find a solution that will not give me design errors so that I can still see my window in design mode.

Answer (score 3):

Even though the xaml interpreter happens to turn the markup extension into something working, this is not really supported.

See [MSDN - Binding Markup Extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750413(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The following are properties of Binding that cannot be set using the Binding markup extension/{Binding} expression form.
>
> - ...
> - ValidationRules: the property takes a generic collection of ValidationRule objects. This could be expressed as a property element in a Binding object element, but has no readily available attribute-parsing technique for usage in a Binding expression. See reference topic for ValidationRules.

However, let me suggest a different approach: instead of nesting the custom markup extension in the binding, nest the binding in a custom markup extension:

```
[ContentProperty("Binding")]
[MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(object))]
public class BindingEnhancementMarkup : MarkupExtension
{
    public BindingEnhancementMarkup()
    {

    }
    public BindingEnhancementMarkup(Binding binding)
    {
        Binding = binding;
    }

    [ConstructorArgument("binding")]
    public Binding Binding { get; set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        Binding.ValidationRules.Add(new NotEmptyValidationRule());
        return Binding.ProvideValue(serviceProvider);
    }
}
```

And use as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{local:BindingEnhancementMarkup {Binding Path=Location, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}}"/>
```

Ofcourse, for production you may want to add a few more checks in the markup extension instead of just assuming everything is in place.

Comment: By the way: you may just as well extend the `Binding` and add the validation rules in there instead of wrapping it.