# How do you set the ValidationRules of a DataGridTextColumn via attribute and not nested tags?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, data-binding, datagridtextcolumn

I've been trying to perform some simple validation logic on a column, and so far I have it working with nested tags:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Property">
    <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
        <Binding Path="Property">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:PropertyValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

But when I try to set the `Binding` attribute:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="IPAddress" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource errorStyle}" 
    Binding="{Binding Path=Property, ValidationRules={StaticResource validateProperty}}">
```

I receive an error stating "The property 'ValidationRules' does not have an accessible setter".  As far as I'm aware the two methods above are equivalent, but I'm clearly missing something.

Can anybody provide an explanation please?

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44296652/can-you-use-a-binding-validationrule-within-1-line-in-xaml

Comment: Yes! Answers my question exactly- thank you very much.